# How do i remove m2eclipse from my eclipse installation?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I don't need m2eclipse to work properly, I just need to remove m2eclipse for now and let eclipse behave normally. how do i do this?

Answer (score 37):

Two solutions:

Remove the plugin through the list of installed plugins
(the illustrations are from the blog post "[Install Eclipse UI Form Editor](http://albertattard.blogspot.com/2009/08/install-eclipse-ui-form-editor.html)" written by [Albert ATTARD](http://www.blogger.com/profile/05001967782991767837)):

[image: install]

The "about eclipse" menu will give you access to the list of installed Software:

[image: uninstall]

You can click on the right application (m2eclipse for you, Jiglo in this example), and click uninstall, and restart eclipse.

---

A safer solution would be first to install a new fresh copy of Eclipse, and add your existing plugins (except m2eclipse): if that fails, you still have your previous Eclipse installation untouched.

Comment: Nice arrows.  Instant visual parsing!

Comment: Sadly when you look on the Plug-ins panel you still see bunch of m2e entries. So if you wanted to get rid of the M2E to resolve some collisions which prevented you from installing something new you are still screwed and have to delete that manually. Gods I hate Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

after doing what VonC suggested, goto the directory eclipse\plugins and search anything with m2e and remove it from the directory
also do the same for the eclipse\features directory.
then you won't be seeing any of the m2e things again.
i would have used m2e if it had a command line feature similar to 
"mvn eclipse:clean" and "mvn eclipse:eclipse"
sadly their both incompatible with each other..
right now all i needed are those two command lines to get me up and running with eclipse just to browse and edit the code, etc..

Comment: actually after playing with m2e..
it's ok.. but i'd still be much happier if they'd have a console command for generating eclipse projects specifics..