# error while using struts2-archetype-starter build project in myeclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, struts2, myeclipse, archetypes

ERROR MESSAGE:

> An internal error occurred during:
>   "Creating struts2-archetype-starter".
>   Attempted to beginRule:
>   MultiRule[P/examsys,P/.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders],
>   does not match outer scope rule:
>   org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.project.SchedulingRule@971a7e

environment:

- MyEclipse 8.5M2 plugin m2eclipse
- struts2-archetype-starter 2.0.11
- apache-maven-2.2.1

have anyone met this situation?help me please.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a MyEclipse specific answer but using the command line works:

```
mvn archetype:create   -DgroupId=tutorial \
                       -DartifactId=tutorial \
                       -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
                       -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-starter \
                       -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1
```

Then, import the project in Eclipse using **Import > Maven Projects**.

Comment: @CunruiLi On my machine, it just works (I tested the command before posting it). And because *"it doesn't work"* is the worst problem description ever, I won't be able to help further.

Comment: sorry,what i said means myeclipse reported the same error message.i think it happend because myeclipse 8.5 m2 integrated m2eclipse 0.9.6,but this version can't work here.can you tell me how to uninstall m2eclipse?thank you.(my english is not good,if you can't understand,please tell me and i will edit my question)

Comment: @CunruiLi No problem. To uninstall m2eclipse, have a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452040/how-do-i-remove-m2eclipse-from-my-eclipse-installation).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git plugin... maybe it could be the problem...

Check your EGit plugin version... an update it... it seams to be a bug fixed... or try updating MyEclipse...

See this thread where i posted my solution:

[check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098879/git-submodules-in-android-project-causes-unable-to-ignore-resources-error/20278288#20278288)