# GIT submodules in android project causes "Unable to ignore resources" error

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I am using eclipse with ADT. Also I have android project with GIT submodules. Until I updated ADT this works very well. I don't clearly remember last ADT version, but it is about 18. Since I updated ADT I get this errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to beginRule: F/Project/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/gen, does not match outer scope rule: MultiRule[F/actionbarsherlock/gen]
```

with message:

```
Unable to ignore resources
```

Sometimes I can't export signet package, but this is totally random case, because after a fail I restart Eclipse and try again and in 3-5 attempts it works. But this procedure very annoying me.

How I can deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be a bug in EGit Eclipse plugin... i had the same problem and error message and i solved updating my EGit plugin for Eclipse... 
In other way... if you are using a custom Eclipse IDE like ADT, JBoss Studio Developer 7,e etc... try updating it... sometimes custom IDE's include EGit plugin inside... and you only need to update the IDE from menu "Help" -> "Check for Updates" or downloading a new IDE version...

If you want, you could read the bug on this link:
[enter link description here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=410011)

And the fix release:
[enter link description here](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/14437/)

Regards