# set up an android test project in eclipse - where, naming conventions etc

Tags: android, eclipse, android-testing

We read at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects)

> You can create a test project anywhere in your file system, but the best approach is to add the test project so that its root directory tests/ is at the same level as the src/ directory of the main application's project. This helps you find the tests associated with an application. For example, if your application project's root directory is MyProject, then you should use the following directory structure:

```
MyProject/
  AndroidManifest.xml
  res/
      ... (resources for main application)
  src/
      ... (source code for main application) ...
  tests/
      AndroidManifest.xml
      res/
          ... (resources for tests)
      src/
          ... (source code for tests)
```

However, if I tell eclipse to create a new project named `tests/` and ask it to create it inside the  MyProject/ folder it fails :

> Unable to ignore resources
>
> Attempted to beginRule: F/AndroidHelpers/tests-test/gen, does not match outer scope rule: MultiRule[F/tests/gen]

Notice it tagged a `-test` suffix to the project folder. Note also that `F/AndroidHelpers/tests-test/gen` is not a path - except if `F` refers to the `${workspace_loc}`

So what are the standard practices for creating/naming test projects in android with eclipse ? *How can I follow the docs guidelines* ? It appears I can't nest projects

EDIT : I want to test a *library project* if it makes a difference - it contains wrappers around `SharedPreferences` etc so I need android specific test classes (I need to get a `Context` etc)
Of note also that android will tag a Test suffix to the app name in `res/values/strings.xml` - so if you name your test project `myAppTest` you will have

```
<string name="app_name">MyAppTestTest</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when i used Git repo with my project...

if you are using Git... it could be a bug in EGit Eclipse plugin... you could solve your problem following this:

[read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098879/git-submodules-in-android-project-causes-unable-to-ignore-resources-error/20278288#20278288)