# How to uninstall a plugin from Eclipse Galileo 3.5?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I have eclipse Galileo 3.5 with maven plugin installed. I want to know if there is any way to uninstall that plugin. I do not see any option as uninstall a plugin in this version if eclipse.

The following is the screen i got after reading one of the comments on this question. but the uninstall button is disabled. What to do?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does my older answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452040/how-do-i-remove-m2eclipse-from-my-eclipse-installation

Comment: i followed it, but i see the uninstall button disabled. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Somebody answer please.... This issue is driving me nuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the problem (and obviously solved it). The problem was I was using IDM as a download manager which used to take over any downloads by eclipse. So i disabled Eclipse from the IDM options and then the maven jars were downloaded where they actually belong to. Problem solved :)