# How to reset maven plugin in android studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I have an android maven project that builds without issues, but maven plugin tab is appearing empty, so I cannot run particular maven goals, and have crashlytics issues. I tried adding maven project (green 'plus' button), but project is already mavenized. I also tried to unset and set again a checkbox against maven plugin in Settings-Plugins.

[image]

Also have this when trying to post any command

> [org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunConfigurationType@7e0d8db1, org.jetbrains.android.run.testing.AndroidTestRunConfigurationType@2bd1a01e, com.google.gct.idea.appengine.run.AppEngineRunConfigurationType@4f67280b, com.intellij.execution.application.ApplicationConfigurationType@7d7612e6, org.intellij.lang.batch.runner.BatchConfigurationType@52d2fa63, org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExternalTaskConfigurationType@1934a410, org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.runner.GroovyScriptRunConfigurationType@4eff235d, com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitConfigurationType@506ad72f, com.intellij.execution.remote.RemoteConfigurationType@165577e8, com.theoryinpractice.testng.configuration.TestNGConfigurationType@45332bcc] loader: PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.idea.maven, null], class org.jetbrains.idea.maven.execution.MavenRunConfigurationType: [org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunConfigurationType@7e0d8db1, org.jetbrains.android.run.testing.AndroidTestRunConfigurationType@2bd1a01e, com.google.gct.idea.appengine.run.AppEngineRunConfigurationType@4f67280b, com.intellij.execution.application.ApplicationConfigurationType@7d7612e6, org.intellij.lang.batch.runner.BatchConfigurationType@52d2fa63, org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExternalTaskConfigurationType@1934a410, org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.runner.GroovyScriptRunConfigurationType@4eff235d, com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitConfigurationType@506ad72f, com.intellij.execution.remote.RemoteConfigurationType@165577e8, com.theoryinpractice.testng.configuration.TestNGConfigurationType@45332bcc] loader: PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.idea.maven, null], class org.jetbrains.idea.maven.execution.MavenRunConfigurationType

Comment: [remove it and reinstall](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2452638/1761003)

Comment: The problem is I'm using android studio...

Comment: Maybe it's a studio new improvement that's forcing new programmers to use gradle.

Comment: The only way to fix this I've found is switch to Intellij IDEA, its for the most part the same as Android Studio